# Compiling AIR iOS .ipa with ADT from the command line

Tags: ios, command-line, air

I'm using Adobe AIR SDK 17 and I'm new to compiling with the command line.
The following .ipa compiling works as long as all files are in the ADT `bin` folder:

```
./adt -package -target ipa-app-store -storetype pkcs12 -keystore iOS7.p12 -provisioning-profile Africa_DragDrop_iPad.mobileprovision Africa_iPad.ipa Africa_iPad-app.xml Africa_iPad.swf AfricaIcon29.png AfricaIcon40.png AfricaIcon48.png AfricaIcon50.png AfricaIcon57.png AfricaIcon58.png AfricaIcon72.png AfricaIcon76.png AfricaIcon80.png AfricaIcon100.png AfricaIcon114.png AfricaIcon120.png AfricaIcon128.png AfricaIcon144.png AfricaIcon152.png AfricaIcon512.png AfricaIcon1024.png Default-Landscape.png
```

I would like to put all files in a seperate folder in `bin`, e.g; `myfiles`, for a better overview. I changed my command line code to:

```
./adt -package -target ipa-app-store -storetype pkcs12 -keystore myfiles/iOS7.p12 -provisioning-profile myfiles/Africa_DragDrop_iPad.mobileprovision myfiles/Africa_iPad.ipa myfiles/Africa_iPad-app.xml myfiles/Africa_iPad.swf myfiles/AfricaIcon29.png myfiles/AfricaIcon40.png myfiles/AfricaIcon48.png myfiles/AfricaIcon50.png myfiles/AfricaIcon57.png myfiles/AfricaIcon58.png myfiles/AfricaIcon72.png myfiles/AfricaIcon76.png myfiles/AfricaIcon80.png myfiles/AfricaIcon100.png myfiles/AfricaIcon114.png myfiles/AfricaIcon120.png myfiles/AfricaIcon128.png myfiles/AfricaIcon144.png myfiles/AfricaIcon152.png myfiles/AfricaIcon512.png myfiles/AfricaIcon1024.png myfiles/Default-Landscape.png
```

I can't compile the .ipa anymore because of a missing files error. (Africa_iPad.swf is missing etc)
I guess my path it wrong? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all the paths inside Africa_iPad-app.xml.  I think, anyway, you should keep your xml and keys outside myfiles because you may get double references (as per see myfiles/myfiles). Other way: use absolute paths (like /something/other/adtbinfolder/myfiles) and see if it still complains.

For reference to different subfolders use -C as per documentation (see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html ):

```
  adt –package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert.p12 myApp.air release/bin/myApp-app.xml  
   –C release/bin myApp.swf (or myApp.html) 
   –C ../artwork/myApp images  
   –C ../libraries/release libs
```